# Convert numeric datasets to images by QR code and name them separately

Tags: python, qr-code

I have a database that contains 2 columns. I wrote a code that turns each of the numbers into an image. Do I have 2 problems?

1. In the process of converting numbers to images, it saves each duplicate image to the previous image if I want all numbers to be images
2. I want the name of the images to be used from the first column
   Thanks someone for helping me write the code

```
import qrcode
from PIL import Image

f = df['Poro']
#Counter(f)
f[1:]

for i in f[1:]:
  qr = qrcode.make(i)
  print(qr)
  print(type(qr))
  qr.save("%s.png"%i)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9dGj.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your code is not indented properly. We don't know what `f` is. Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), including a small example input data and the corresponding expected result. Don't paste code or data as images.

Comment: Hi Dear Pierre D
it was corrected. thank

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `df` has a simple `RangeIndex` (0,1,2,...) and at least one column named `'Poro'`, you can do this:

```py
for i, r in df.iterrows():
    value = r['Poro']
    filename = f'qr_{i:02d}.png'
    qr = qrcode.make(value)
    qr.save(filename)
    display(qr)
    print(f'saved as {filename}')
```

Note: this is in a Jupyter notebook, where `display` is defined to show the image in the notebook. In a Python script, just skip this line. And of course, remove that line and the print one if you have many rows to make into qr codes. The files saved by the above are named `qr_00.png`, `qr_01.png`, etc. Change the filename as you need.

For testing:

```py
# reproducible setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'Poro': [0.050551, 0.056821]})
>>> df
       Poro
0  0.050551
1  0.056821
```

Then the code above produces:

[image]

Comment: Hi Pierre D I am a beginner and I had another question. If according to the image, I have multiple columns instead of one and I want to put the values of several columns in the value parameter in the code, I actually want the values of several columns in each row to be converted to an image, then how does the code change?

Comment: OR ,
If I want to explain more, I have an Excel file with several columns that first convert the values of each column to QR code and then convert all the QR code to one QR code.

Comment: Best to rephrase the question or open a new one... Make sure to attach a short but representative sample of data in your question, typeset as code and in a way that's easy to copy/paste.